# Shifting a vector in C++20

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++20

I'd like to use this new feature from C++20 of shifting a vector to the right `std::shift_right`.

Something that I'm not sure about is how can I get the last element to the beginning of the vector after shifting?

Like in the example above... Where I'm saving the last element in a temp variable and then after shifting I set the first element to be the temp variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> seq = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    std::vector<int>::iterator temp;
    temp = seq.end() - 1;


    std::shift_right(seq.begin(), seq.end(), 1);
    std::replace(seq.begin(), seq.end(), seq.at(0), *temp);

    for (it = seq.begin(); it != seq.end(); it = std::next(it))
        std::cout << *it << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can probably achieve what you want with `std::shift_right`, the appropriate algorithm to do what you've described is `std::rotate`, which you can use without c++20 as well:

```
std::rotate(seq.begin(), seq.end() - 1, seq.end());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aWfez6).

The reason the `shift_right` version doesn't work is that you have an iterator to the last element. When you finish shifting, the original last element is overwritten, and the iterator now points to the shifted element instead. So what you can do is make a copy of the last *element* and then put that at the beginning:

```
int temp = seq.back();
std::shift_right(seq.begin(), seq.end(), 1);
seq[0] = temp;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vEM9ee).  But note that this is a hack; use `shift_right` if you don't care about those elements that you are overwriting. If you care about the elements, then `rotate` the range.

Comment: and to the left?

Comment: Just change the iterators that you pass to `rotate`.

Comment: Oops, I changed the direction of the rotation in the original answer. Edited it to make it match the `shift_right` version.

Comment: @JeJo Oh yeah, much better, thanks :) edited the answer.